VS Code File Nesting for resx doesn't work
I'm trying to nest *.resx files with their corresponding *.cs (Form) files and it is not working.
This is the related configuration:
    "explorer.fileNesting.enabled": true,
    "explorer.fileNesting.patterns": {
        "*.cs": "$(capture).resx, $(capture).*.cs"
    },

Here is the result showing it not working:

Any idea how to get that to behave?
